# findstr returns nothing in windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, findstr

In windows cmd, temp dir is set to

```
 C:\spec>echo %temp%
 C:\Users\mahmood\AppData\Local\Temp
```

also there is a file %temp%\specdev.txt which contain

```
 C:\spec>type %temp%\specdev.txt
 c:\cpu
```

Now when I execute this command

```
findstr -r "^[a-zA-Z]:$" %temp%\specdev.txt >nul 2>&1
```

it doesn't return anything!!

```
C:\spec>findstr -r "^[a-zA-Z]:$" %temp%\specdev.txt >nul 2>&1

C:\spec>
```

What is the problem?? Can you explain what does this command do? it is part of a batch script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot see any results because all console outputs are redirected to NUL: the last part of the command `>nul` redirects standard output to NUL and `2>&1` redirects error output to standard output (therefore, NUL).

Because this command is part of a script, it does not mean it is useless: FINDSTR sets the global environment variable `%ERRORLEVEL%` to 0 when it finds a match and set it to 1 when doesn't find. Thus, a script can send all output to NUL (not to clog user screen) and check `%ERRORLEVEL%` to verify the results.

About the pattern this command is searching for, `"^[a-zA-Z]:$"` means that it searches for a line that only contains a single letter from "a" to "z" (uppercase and lowercase) and ends with a colon ":". Thus, the file `%temp%\specdev.txt` you described will not match the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead:

```
findstr -r "^[a-zA-Z]*$" %temp%\specdev.txt >nul 2>&1
```

Comment: this is the same as what I wrote!!

Comment: Your original posting has a colon where mine above has the *.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the string doesn't match the regular expression, which matches lines that consist of nothing but a single letter followed by `':'` character.

So now the question is, what pattern do you really want to match? Maybe you want:

```
"^[a-zA-Z]:"
```

which will match lines that start with a letter followed by a `':'` (but can then have other characters following that on the line).  But I suspect you want something more complex.

Comment: i want to run the command in http://www.spec.org/cpu2006/Docs/install-guide-windows.html#s5 the findstr syntax should not be changed. Your answer mean that my input is wrong. So please suggest something that match the syntax

Comment: It's still not 100% clear to me what you need. I think that maybe you need to post a question specifically about your problem installing SPEC. I think also that the question might be more appropriate for the superuser.com StackExchange site.  If you do that, be sure to copy/paste the command and the error output into the question.